# Monitoring comments on answers to your question

Tags: feature-request, comments

You are automatically informed of comments made on a question that you have posted or an answer you have made without people having to `@` mention your username.

The proposal:

The ability to have the feature above extended so that if someone comments on an answer to your question, you will be notified, even if you were not the person to write the answer. This would be an 'opt-in' feature.

Comment: That'd be an awful lot of noise. As a opt-in feature, maybe. But not as the default

Comment: @Pekka웃 An opt-in feature is what I was suggestion - updating question...

Comment: @rene The feature request is not a duplicate - the link provided asks for notification if an answer is _modified_.

Comment: MSE related: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32090/can-you-notify-questions-op-when-any-answer-is-commented), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70618/can-i-be-notified-immediately-for-every-comment-or-answer-to-my-questions), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196508/do-i-get-notified-if-any-comments-in-answer-for-my-question), [4](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/receive-notifications-for-comments-on-any-answers-to-your-question)

Comment: Although it can not be marked as duplicate. Those links are duplicates though. Thank you @rene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are automatically informed of comments on your **posts** (answers *and* questions).

IMO, It's annoying to get a notification on every comment dropped on one of the answers to one of my questions.

While comments can be informative, they might be very noisy. I really don't want to get a notification on comments like:

- "Can you please explain why.."
- "Thanks for.."
- "You saved my day.."

Having it as an opt-in feature might be better (although I don't support this either).